# How to check user's manager IsActive status?

Tags: apex, map, user

My requirement is I have to check the status of user's manager(we have a manager field on user object) whether he is active or not.If manager is not active then I have to assign all user's open opportunities to specific user(Director).
Can someone help how I am going to achieve this by creating a map?
I have never used map before and I do not know how to use map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to use a `Map` in this way, I would suggest create a `Map<Id, Boolean>` to store User Ids and whether they're active or not.

The reason I suggest using an `Id` as the key is, because, whilst you could do something like `Map<String, Boolean>` where you're storing the name of the person (as a `String`) and the `isActive` `Boolean`, you could run in to the problem of duplicate names. What if there were two people called John Doe? If there were, the `Map` would ignore any duplicates. **Keys are unique**.

Anyway, to do this, you would need to create a new map, query your User and populate the map:

```
Map<Id, Boolean> mapUserToActive = new Map<Id, Boolean>();

for (User u : [SELECT Id, isActive FROM User]) { // Query and loop through each User
  mapUserToActive.put(u.Id, u.isActive);
}
```

Next, you'll need to identify the manager and as a result, you can get whether or not they're active! That might look something like this:

```
User someone = [SELECT Manager.Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; // Get the manager Id of the current, logged in User

if (mapUserToActive.get(someone.Manager.Id)== true) { // Get the value of the the returned Id (they key) and check if the boolean is true
  System.debug('@@@@@ They\'re active!'); // If it's true, debug this!
}
else {
  System.debug('@@@@@ They\'re not active.'); // Otherwise it must be false, debug this instead.
}
```

@KeithC rightly points out that you *could* have over 50,000 Users. In which case you will run into an exception. You could always consider using a `Set`, storing **only active users**. This would work by populating a `Set` similar to below, but only getting active Users:

```
Set<Id> activeUsers = new Set<Id>();

for (User u : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE isActive = true]) {
  activeUsers.add(u.Id);
}
```

Now you could use this to check if a User exists in this list, if they don't they must be inactive!

```
for (User u : [SELECT Id, Manager.Id FROM User]) { // Loop through Users and their managers
  if (activeUsers.contains(u.Manager.Id)) { // If the manager Id is in the list of active people...
    System.debug('@@@@@ Active!'); // ... Debug this...
  }
  else {
    System.debug('@@@@@ Not active!'); // ... Otherwise debug this.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope the org has less than 50,000 users in it.

Comment: @KeithC You're right. I added something that would handle that a bit better. If you had over 50k Active Users, I'd personally probably resort to a Batch class that I'd later delete to sort the initial records out and a Trigger to handle it going forward.

Comment: @DanJones Thank You so much Dan.Could you please look at below link:    http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150152/new-opportunity-owner-is-not-receiving-email-notification-in-proper-sequence-and                                    Please check the link and let me know if you can suggest anything.This is the similar requirement